# Adding Objects More Than To ArrayList

Tags: c#, xna, arraylist

I'm developing a simple shooter game in XNA. I'm adding the copy of the object to an array list whenever it hits an hostile. The problem is, the object is added 2 times.

Here is the code:

--> Player fires spheres.

--> s is fired sphere

--> sp is copy of s

--> a sphere is drawn iff it's active

```
if(s.isCollided)
{
     s.isCollided = false;
     Sphere sp = new Sphere(s.texture, new Vector2(s.dest_rectangle.X,s.dest_rectangle.Y), s.speed);
     s.dest_rectangle = new Rectangle((int)s.position.X, (int)s.position.Y, s.texture.Width, s.texture.Height);
     sp.isActive = true;
     sp.isCollided = false;
     collidedSpheres.Add(sp);
 }
```

Comment: This part of the code probably isn't the culprit, if possible could you should the function that this is located in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that `s` is colliding with your hostile during two "frames".

You could try adding this line to the end of your function: `spheres.Remove(s);`.

Do the duplicate spheres have the same position?

Comment: But what if, by any chance, it will once collide in just one frame? Or even more? I don't know any XNA, but take precaution! (Lag or bullet speed?)

Comment: If it collides in just one frame it will be added to the sp list once. If he wants it to be added for more than one frame he needs to get rid of his s.isCollided check.